# Microsoft.Graph.QueryOption type is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I have .NET 6 console application and installed two Nuget packages

- Azure.Identity (1.9)
- Microsoft.Graph (5.12)

however following code does not work

[image]

the `Microsoft.Graph.QueryOption` type could not be found, but it should be available in the `Microsoft.Graph` package based on following documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.queryoption?view=graph-core-dotnet

[image]

any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might downgrade your graph package to v4.x.

[image]

That's because in V5.x SDK, QueryOption class is [no longer used](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#query-parameter-options).

> To pass query Options, the QueryOption class is no longer used. Query
> options are set using the requestConfiguration modifier as follows

```
var user = await graphServiceClient
    .Users["{user-id}"]
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration => requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "id", "createdDateTime"});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are [breaking changes](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#query-parameter-options) in SDK v5 and the `QueryOption` class is no longer there.

In v4 there was only one class `QueryOption` for all requests builders, but in SDK v5 there is a specific `<xxx>QueryParameters` class for each endpoint and request type like `MessagesRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters`, `ApplicationsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters` etc.

You will need to create some custom class for query parameters.